Could not load type '..RenderModeInteractiveAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web'
I have a Blazor Web solution where in the Program.cs of the startup project the following before "app.Run();" is throwing an error:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()    
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);

The error reads as follows:
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.TypeLoadException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 
'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderModeInteractiveAutoAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

Not sure how to go about fixing this, any help would be great, thanks.

I ultimately did the following to resolve the issue, 1st I updated the nuget packages to the latest (8.0.8 at the times of this post):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server

For reference after updating you can check your cs.proj files and you will see the version in the package reference elements updated.
Next, I updated "_Imports.razor" to include the following:
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode

Finally, I found the Razor Syntax for using the render mode auto changed, you will have to update your pages using the following syntax from:
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveAuto]

to
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

